Running Electron on Linux Wayland on a 32-bit ARM machine
I'm having an headache on this problem:
I have to run Electron on an embedded machine (32-bit ARM) for which X11 is no longer supported, so I want to move to Wayland to have better support and possibly better performance.
I know that Electron can run on Wayland, I use it everyday on my desktop PC. I also know that Electron support for 32-bit machines has stopped, but I still find prebuilt binaries of Electron on Git for arm32 devices.
However running:
readelf -d

on this binary suggest that still require X11 libraries to work.
Is this image a older version of electron which requires X11 or is it a newer version, but built with X11 dependencies instead of Wayland ones?
If so, are there any chances to build Electron for a 32-bit ARM Wayland Linux machine?
